# Probability of at least 4 cards of the same denomination out of 13

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$13$ out of $52$ cards are chosen randomly. My task is to calculate the probability that these $13$ cards will contain all $4$ of at least one of the $13$ denominations. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inclusion-Exclusion should work here.

Let $c_1$ be the condition that all aces are in the $13$ chosen cards. And similuarly define $c_i$ up to $i=13$. Now to calculate all the combinations we have:

$$P = \sum P(c_i) - \sum P(c_i,c_j) + P(c_i,c_j,c_k)$$
$$P = \frac{\binom{13}{1} \cdot \binom{48}{9} - \binom{13}{2} \cdot \binom{44}{5} + \binom{13}{3} \cdot \binom{40}{1}}{\binom{52}{13}} \approx 0.0342$$

Comment: Why do you subtract (13 choose 2) * (44 choose 5)

Comment: @SargsyanGrigor [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @SargsyanGrigor That is to take care of the double counting. When a set of 13 cards contains two full denominations we have counted it twice, instead of just once.